# На сколько методов нужно разделять код в ООП?

Tags: java, ооп

Можно написать программу не вызывая ни одного метода из main, а можно дойти до маразма и объединять каждые 2 строки, хоть немного логически связанные.
**Какие есть правила, принципы, придерживаясь которых можно было отвечать на вопрос – объединить ли участок кода в метод?**

Comment: Думаю, что нужно выносить в метод, если код будет много раз встречаться в программе; как при наследовании. Но можно тоже переборщить. Как бы уточнить правило.

Comment: _Есть ли какое-то универсальное правило, что бы отвечать на вопрос – объединить ли участок кода в метод?_ - такого правила нет

Comment: здравым смыслом такой принцип называется

Comment: в общем случае один метод должен выполнять одно простое законченное действие

Comment: почитайте GRASP

Answer (score 4):

Следует придерживаться принципа единственной ответственности.

1. Каждый класс должен решать лишь одну задачу.
2. Каждая подзадача может быть решена независимо.
3. Полученные решения могут быть объединены вместе, позволяя решить исходную задачу.

Если класс отвечает за решение нескольких задач, его подсистемы, реализующие решение этих задач, оказываются связанными друг с другом. Изменения в одной такой подсистеме ведут к изменениям в другой.  Этого следует избегать.